# Is it standard to access an static method from other classes?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and object oriented programming, I have some functions that should wait for each other (promises in JavaScript) and promises are depending on each other, for example:

In the main script file, I have the main class, and I imported other files and classed inside it. *(I mean using `import {bla-bla-class} from "bla-bla"` )*

I had a `promise` for `load` *(depending on the page and internet speed may take some milliseconds or seconds...)* using `addEventListener` and `configSetter` method is `awaited` for that method *(`load`)* to set the configs *(I needed the page be completely loaded for setting the configs)*, then I needed to tell `ready()` method in my `main` class that the page is loaded and configs set correctly, because of this I added another `promise` for `ready()` method inside the `main` class to wait for `configSetter()` method *(because the config setter itself needed to wait for `load` method, `ready()` was also depending on it, so I need to wait)*, when I compiled and bundled files, the file was heavier than what I was expecting, and also my TypeScript files was more complicated to understand because of differents `promises` I used

I thought maybe I can export the `main` class and also make its `ready()` method `static`, so I could access my main class's `ready()` method from another class easily, but now I am not sure, if is this something that people do in object oriented programming?

Is it okay to use the main class's methods (even as static) inside other classes and methods? (specially when they are not main classes and are just some helpful methods... should they be able to call the `main` class methods?)

Comment: long question, but a good one.  I also need to know the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: when to use static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)

Comment: @Igor but that is in Java, here is JavaScript. But I agree that the main concepts must be same. thanks

Comment: @Igor, can you please shortly answer my question? If is that the standard way of static methods since that was the main class's method? thank you

Comment: @Igor I also think you can give a short answer this user...

Answer (score 0):

The main use for `static` functions would be to offer utility functions which do not operate on a specific instance (like the `Math` class for example. You do not need an instance of `Math` to perform math functions because that is both unnecessary use of memory and somewhat illogical).

Another use for `static` is sharing a common resource between multiple instances of the same class. I'll cite an example from Angular >= 2.x development:

Suppose you have a service for logging in and logging out users. Trying to keep the user profile a non-static field will lead to unexpected `undefined` values for the user profile in some use cases despite logging in. That is because the user profile is not shared across instances. Making it `static` ensures the field is one and the same for each instance of the class.

This is true for OOP in general.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no, I am not using Angular 2, I am just learning TypeScript

Comment: @TypeScriptLearner the general principles still apply, sharing the same object across instances of a class :)